# How Do I Find Matching Ethereum Transactions Based On The Amount Of Ethereum Sent?

Tags: blockchain, transactions, explorers, filters, explorer-api

I am trying to locate a specific transaction on the Ethereum blockchain.

I know the approximate amount which was sent, and that it was sent in 2019. I do not know the from address, to address, hash, or anything else.

I would like to filter and find matching transactions on the Ethereum blockchain quickly. The amount was large, so there shouldn't be that many.

All of the blockchain explorers I've found don't seem to support these kinds of searches or I can't get it working. I looked at https://etherscan.io/, https://ethplorer.io/, and https://www.etherchain.org/, and none of them seem to support this search or I can't find it. I have tried searching lots of different terms and not found anything helpful.

The only blockchain explorer I was able to find with this kind of search was blockchair (https://blockchair.com/ethereum/transactions). It seems like it has what I need, but when I hit the "Filter" icon next to "Value > ETH" and then "Between" and enter a range, then hit "Apply", all of the transactions still showed up and there doesn't seem to be any filter applied at all. After some time of trying, it's now saying No Results when I apply any filter, even if I choose a range which I can see valid transactions within.

How can I do this kind of search quickly and preferably online?

Answer (score 0):

According to blockchair.com, for tasks like extracting lots of blockchain data (e.g. all transactions over a 2 month period) it's better to use dumps feature instead of using API or other services. It's possible to download the database dumps in TSV format and insert the data onto your own database server (like Postgresql or whatever) to further analyze it. You can try to use dumps:

Ethereum transaction dump: https://gz.blockchair.com/ethereum/transactions/

Answer (score 0):

Use a node as service like Alchemy or Infura. It won't be the fastest way and you will have to iterate over a large number of blocks but it will do the job for sure. Also you would be able to apply more complex filters.